# Need help comparing Laptops with best speed RAM

Tags: windows-8, laptop, memory, cpu, cpu-speed

I am planning to buy Lenovo Yoga 2 11.6 Laptop,

but I do not understand

1. The difference between the RAM in comparison.
2. Windows OS.
3. Hard Drive.

Thanks,
Here is Screenshot. Link to screenshot. [bigger pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ID2g.png)
[image]

Comment: One obvious difference is in some units, the RAM is soldered to the systemboard.  That means you can't expand it or replace it if it fails.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  The difference between the soldered memory and the SODIMM option is clear.

Comment: I am asking which one is fast of course, you must be kidding me for voting down. @fixer1234 Thanks for excellent advice.

Comment: If you are asking about the Windows versions and hard disks, the hard disks appear to be the same.  Windows is offered in 32 and 64 bit versions.  The world moved to 64 bit some time ago and you would not be able to run 64 bit software with the 32 bit OS (although you don't buy this type of device to run big applications).  The 32 bit OS is slightly smaller, which would leave a little more RAM available for use and can address all of the resources you would likely connect to such a device.  SST is irrelevant, just a discount Lenovo gets from Microsoft for putting Windows on a small device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System soldiered means it is soldiered, you cannot replace ever. 
DIMM meand it is on board, plugged in, you can replace in future.

Windows 8.1 standard means same as Desktop OD
windows 8.1 SST means optimized for smaller touch screen,
Hard drive is all same.

Comment: would you recommend buying the first one on left? thanks

Comment: Yes. You can buy that...